# Why does setCount not increase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Small app to upload files, when doing so I would like to get the progress of each completed item.
However the setCount doesn't increase each time the file is uploaded to firebase, it only increases by one everytime after it has entire upload has been completed..

```
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage"
import { proStorage } from "../firebase/config"
import { v4 } from "uuid"
import { useState } from "react"

const useUploader = (data, foldername) => {
  const [upLoadcomplete, setuploacomplete] = useState("")
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const uploadFiles = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const name = `$${v4()}`
      const location = `${foldername}/${name}`
      const metadata = {
        customMetadata: {
          uuid_name: name,
        },
      }
      const dataRef = ref(proStorage, location)
      const uploadtask = uploadBytesResumable(dataRef, data[i], metadata)

      uploadtask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done")
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          switch (snapshot.state) {
            case "paused":
              console.log("Upload is paused")
              break
            case "running":
              console.log("Upload is running")
              setCount( count + 1 )
              break
          }
          setuploacomplete("complete")
        },
        (error) => {
          setuploacomplete("Error with upload try again")
        }
      )
    }
    console.log(upLoadcomplete)
  }
  return [uploadFiles, upLoadcomplete]
}
export default useUploader
```

It looks like setCount should increase each time the status is changed to running.. but it doesn't?

Any ideas

Comment: Since state updating is not synchronous, maybe `count` hasn't been incremented by the time it's called again? Try using a state update function instead `setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)`?

Comment: This kinda works, except it seems to first take the total amount to upload and add the iterations over that.. for example upload 5 files, it reports 5 and then 6,7,8,9,10. Adding a 0.5 does work.. but less ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you initialise `count` as 0. This means that this code:

```js
const [upLoadcomplete, setuploacomplete] = useState("")
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
const uploadFiles = async () => {
  // ...
  setCount(count + 0)
  // ...
}
```

effectively becomes

```js
const [upLoadcomplete, setuploacomplete] = useState("")
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
const uploadFiles = async () => {
  // ...
  setCount(0 + 1) // always sets count to 1
  // ...
}
```

As covered by [@evolutionxbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989920) in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77171279/why-does-setcount-not-increase#comment136045488_77171279), one way to work around this is to call `setCount` with a callback function that takes the old value and returns a new one.

```js
const [upLoadcomplete, setuploacomplete] = useState("")
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
const uploadFiles = async () => {
  // ...
  setCount(oldCount => oldCount + 1) // always adds 1 to the previous value
  // ...
}
```

As you noticed in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77171279/why-does-setcount-not-increase/77172059#comment136045893_77171279), while this works, you run into some concurrency issues. When you call `uploadFiles` to start the uploads, all 5 uploads are started at the same time and each calls  `setCount(oldCount => oldCount + 1)`. This causes your initial count to be 5 (as expected). However, for each subsequent `state_changed` event where the state is `running`, you will increment that counter again (resulting in `count` reaching any number depending on how large your files are).

To fix this, you need to make sure you only call `setCount` once for each upload.

```
const useUploader = (data, foldername) => {
  const [upLoadcomplete, setuploacomplete] = useState("")
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const uploadFiles = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // ...
      const uploadtask = // ...
      let started = false;

      uploadtask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          console.log("Upload thread #"+ i + " is " + progress + "% done")
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          switch (snapshot.state) {
            case "paused":
              console.log("Upload is paused")
              break
            case "running":
              console.log("Upload is running")
              if (!started) {
                setCount(oldCount => oldCount + 1)
                started = true;
              }
              break
          }
          // removed: setuploacomplete("complete") (it shouldn't be here)
        },
        (error) => {
          // this upload has encountered an error (but not necessarily all of them)
          setuploacomplete("Error with upload try again")
        },
        () => {
          // this upload has completed (but not necessarily all of them)
        }
      )
    }
  }
  return [uploadFiles, upLoadcomplete];
}
```

Unfortunately, this will still start the count at 5, and then never change it again.  It also may never set the count if the upload completed before getting around to handling a `state_changed` event. If you want to update the count as each upload finishes, you should move that logic to the `onComplete` callback instead:

```js
// ...
() => {
  // this upload has completed (but not necessarily all of them)
  setCount(oldCount => oldCount + 1) // increments count, only once the upload finishes
}
// ...
```

But now you have a problem where `count` may not ever reach the length of `data`, because any upload may end up in an error. While you could add the same `setCount` logic to the error handler, fixing these concurrency issues is beyond the scope of this answer.

Instead, you would be better off creating a new `UploadTask` component which handles a single upload and manages its intermediate states appropriately. Then when you have an array like `data`, you would use an `UploadTaskBatch` component that spawns one `UploadTask` component for each entry in `data`. This allows you to let React do the heavy lifting for handling the concurrent state updates for you. Implementing these is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: wow... that is a very comperhensive answer and thank you so much! I will try it out and see how things go! Once again, thanks so much for explaing things, I am learning as I go and its awesome to get such help.